# how to focus on div element, not working properly on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is working fine on Google Chrome, but not on Firefox,
if a div is focused by mouse at that time if a user press any key on keyboard, the Mozilla search box is appearing on the screen. I want to know how to solve this problem. Why is Mozilla search box is appearing??

```
<div id="mainwindow" onmouseover="this.focus()" tabindex="0" >some Text</div>
```

Comment: As I remember a div is not focusable by definition, so Firefox is working correctly I guess.

Comment: Without saying you want to focus on div element, can you explain *why* you're trying to do this?  There's probably a much simpler (and sensible) way to achieve what you want.

Comment: the code in the question is not enough to give you any help ... how does giving a div focus produce the magical searchbox? there must be some other code involved, and if you shared a minimal, complete and verifiable example of that code, there may be some help forthcoming

Comment: i.e. "why isn't this code working" should include the code that isn't working

Comment: i want to make compare div text charater with keychar code and hightlight on on div. similar to typing

Comment: like this link :- https://www.speedtypingonline.com/typing-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
style>
            #foc{
                width: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 1;
                background-color: #66339900;
                color: #00ff6600;
                border: none;
                outline: none;
                height: 1px;
            }
            </style>
<div id="mainwindow" onkeypress="runMyFunction()" ><input type="text" id="foc" tabindex="0"/><span>some Text</span></div>
```

** This code work proper for Mozila firefox and other browser's**